# How to redirect a page with header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, koa, koa2

I want to redirect a page to modify a post with header. but I saw that redirection with header is technically impossible.

If I send get request to Node server with header to redirect the page to posting modify page, there's no way to redirect to the page with header without using multiple router (because the router function is just for rendering pug file, they  can't be done at the same time)